# Disabled Text Input with on button click

Tags: jquery

With the code shown below, I would like to disable the text input when the user clicks on the button.

When I click on my button, the text input only disables for one second, before it enables again.

**I would like to know why does this happens.**

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#enable').click(function() {
                $('#textBox').removeAttr("disabled")
            });
            $('#disable').click(function() {
                $('#textBox').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="textBox" />
        <button id="enable">Enable</button>
        <button id="disable">Disable</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It works fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v6oxd4zp/. Can you set up a working example of the problem. There's nothing in your code which would cause a change in DOM state after a timed interval.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - you forgot the form element -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/v6oxd4zp/1/

Comment: @adeneo yep, you're right. Let this be a lesson to everyone - ***indent your code!***

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan@adeneo- thanks for giving the answer.

Answer (score 3):

A button inside a form submits the form, reloading the page, as it's default type is `submit`.

You have to either change the type

```
<input type="button" id="enable" value="Enable">
```

or prevent the default

```
$('#enable').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#textBox').prop("disabled", false);
});
$('#disable').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#textBox').prop("disabled", true);
});
```

And use `prop()` for the disabled **property**.